# Obtaining a list of existing UILocalNotifications and modifying their dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to schedule several `UILocalNotification`s, and I need to have access to the already created notifications.

Is it possible to have a list/array of all the `UILocalNotification`s created? Can I edit the fire date of an existing local notification?

This is the code I use for creating local notifications:

```
 UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
 localNotification.alertBody = textFieldName.text;
 localNotification.alertAction = @"Item date expired!";
 localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
 localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can get all `UILocalNotifications` with below code

```
UIApplication* objApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray*    oldNotifications = [objApp scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

and also you can cancel that Notification with bellow code..

```
if ([oldNotifications count] > 0)
    [objApp cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Also see one basic demo with tutorial for `UILocalNotification` from below link

[iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/)

Answer (score 6):

to retrieve current notifications

```
NSArray *currentNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

edit the content of this array (you might have to create a mutable copy first) and then set it back using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setScheduledLocalNotifications:myNotifications];
```

myNotifications containing both the old pending notifications and your new ones, it will override the old values, so by editing the fireDate of the UILocalNotification objects in this array you can change the date they will be fired at.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get all local notification list from below statement:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

And For edit, i have not tried it but yes, can are able to modify fire date of notification.
But my suggestion is, get all other detail of notification and delete and recreate new notification.

Thanks